# Merging two shapefiles with disparate attributes and keeping attributes of both using QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, vector-layer, census, union

I have two shapefiles of NYC--one of city council districts and another shapefile of the census blocks inside NYC. I want to merge these two shapefiles so that I can see what blocks lie inside of each census district in NYC.

[image: districts]

[image: blocks]

Ideally, I want to merge them in a way that results in a shapefile with an attribute table that has *both* the blocks and districts listed. Here are the current attribute tables:

[image: block attributes]

[image: district attributes]

When I tried to simply merge them using vector>data managementment>merge vector layer I get a shapefile that includes both geometries, but only displays districts, and the resulting attribute table is full of null values.

Here is that attribute table:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest would be a spatial join, Vector->Data Management Tools->Join Attributes by Location.  I think this would accomplish your needs.  The information you want can be seen by using the Identify Tool, or the Attribute Table, or by exporting a new layer with the attributes you want.

Another option is either Intersect or Union.  This is a bit messier and would probably need some cleanup to deal with sliver polygons, etc.  As a secondary action Dissolve would clean it up if you want to simplify them afterwards, but I'm not sure this is what you are looking for.

Comment: The spatial join worked perfectly. Thank you so much! I'd been tearing my hair our for a few days.